# ¿Cómo capturo los datos de un SqlDataReader que están en una clase en una función?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Estoy trabajando con vb.net y en la clase `conexion` tengo el siguiente método:

```
Function consulta()

Try
    conectar()
    comando = conexion.CreateCommand()
    comando.CommandText = "select * from persona"

    reader = comando.ExecuteReader()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error 1 " + ex.ToString)
End Try

desconectar()

Return reader
End Function
```

El objeto `reader` es de tipo `SqlDataReader`.

Lo que necesito no es introducir los resultados en un `DataGrid`, sino llamarlos desde el formulario y mostrar cada campo en un `TextBox`. Por ejemplo el campo `nombre` introducirlo en un `TextBox`, el `apellido` en otro `TextBox`.

Comment: y cual es el problema? no queda claro donde esta tu problema...

Comment: En el formulario, al llamar la funcion, no se en que tipo de variable debo almacenar el valor de retorno, para luego usar el While .Read()

Comment: intenté con reader = conexion.consulta() y luego While reader.Read() pero no funcionó

Comment: Agrega todo lo que probaste... pero si devuelves un reader, cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 2 problemas muy serios y fundamentales en el diseño actual que tienes y que las otras respuestas no han mencionado:

1. Estás empleando variables globales para la conexión y el `SqlDataReader`.
2. Estás cerrando la conexión (`desconectar()`) antes de devolver el `SqlDataReader`, de modo que cuando trates de leer los datos con el `SqlDataReader`, te va a lanzar excepciones.

Vez tras vez estoy viendo preguntas donde se está usando ese patrón de emplear conexiones globales. Esto es muy mala práctica y te va a causar problemas en programas mas serios. No hay nada malo en centralizar el código que abre la conexión. Pero no es correcto de guardar la conexión en una variable global.

Y el problema con el segundo punto es que para poder devolver un `SqlDataReader` y poder seguir usándolo, la conexión debe quedar abierta. Pero si quitas la llamada `desconectar()` de tu método para arreglar este problema, ahora tu código se pone aún mas frágil de lo que ya es, porque no queda muy claro quién tiene la responsabilidad de cerrar la conexión.

Aquí te dejo un patrón mucho más solido y reutilizable que puedes emplear para leer los datos de un `SqlDataReader` para cualquier consulta y que no cae en los problemas de diseño mencionados arriba.

Para el ejemplo que te comparto, voy a asumir que en vez de tener un método `conectar()` que abre una conexión y la asigna a una variable global (a evitar), mas bien voy a asumir que has definido un método `CrearConexion` que simplemente devuelve una nueva instancia de `SqlConnection` sin asignarla a una variable global (correcto). Algo como:

```vb
Public Function CrearConexion() As SqlConnection
    Return New SqlConnection("<cadena de conexión>")
End Function
```

**Método `EjecutarLeerConsulta`:**

```vb
Public Sub EjecutarLeerConsulta(
    sql As String,
    leerRegistro As Action(Of SqlDataReader),
    ParamArray parametros As SqlParameter())

    Using conn As SqlConnection = CrearConexion()
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros)
            conn.Open()

            Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While (reader.Read())
                    leerRegistro(reader)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Con este método, puedes ejecutar y leer cualquier consulta usando las mejores prácticas, sin variables globales, sin tener que preocuparte de cuando abrir y cerrar la conexión, etc. Todo está manejado automáticamente en este método central.

**Cómo usarlo**

Para usar el método, necesitas pasarle por lo menos 2 parámetros:

- La cadena SQL.
- Una expresión lambda que define el código que debe ejecutarse para cada registro devuelto por la consulta.
- (Opcional) Una lista de parámetros (`SqlParameter`) si la consulta las necesita.

Ejemplo:

```vb
EjecutarLeerConsulta(
    "select * from persona",
    Sub(reader)
        Dim nombre As String = reader("nombre")
        Dim apellido As String = reader("apellido")
        ' agrega código aquí que asigna los valores a los TextBox o lo que quieras.
    End Sub)
```

Y si necesitas armar consultas con parámetros, la llamada se vería así:

```vb
EjecutarLeerConsulta(
    "select * from persona where nombre = @nombre and apellido = @apellido",
    Sub(reader)
        Dim nombre As String = reader("nombre")
        Dim apellido As String = reader("apellido")
        ' agrega código aquí que asigna los valores a los TextBox o lo que quieras.
    End Sub,
    New SqlParameter("@nombre", "John"),
    New SqlParameter("@apellido", "Smith"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero te recomiendo que agregues al método al final el tipo que vas a devolver. De esta forma:

```
Function consulta() As SQLDataReader
End Function
```

ahora para obtener los datos del data reader lo haces de esta forma

```
'Llamas a tu función para obtener el lector de datos
Dim l = consulta()
'Evaluas si tiene columnas
If l.HasRows Then
    'Evaluas si se leyerón los datos. NOTA: Esto es en caso que solo sea una
    'fila que vas a leer, si son varias te recomiendo usar While l.Read()

    If l.Read() Then
        'obtienes los datos y los agregas donde mayor te convenga

        TextBox1.Text = l["Dato1"].ToString()
        TextBox2.Text = l["Dato2"].Tostring()
        Label1.Text = l["Dato3"].ToString()
        Label2.Text = l["Dato4"].ToString()
        Dim dato5 As Integer = Integer.Parse(l["Dato5"].ToString())

        '....... etc
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza la clase SQLDataReader, en c# puedes llamarlo por indice o por nombre de columna de la siguiente forma

```
 NombreTextBox.Text = VariableDataReader["NombreColumna"].ToString();
```